# Converting a my-sql query to nhibernate queryover

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Could someone please help me or get me started with converting this query to an nhibernate queryover query?

```
SELECT
    Campaign.Id,
    Location.Name,
    Location.PrimaryPostcode,
    Inventory.Section,
    Campaign.Sov,
    IFNULL(Contracts.Spend, 0) AS Spend,
    IFNULL(Contracts.Impressions, 0) AS Impressions,
    IFNULL(Days, 0) Days,
    RenewalDate,
    LastContract.OptIn
FROM
    Contract AS Campaign
    JOIN Inventory ON Campaign.InventoryId = Inventory.Id
    JOIN Location ON Inventory.LocationId = Location.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            CampaignId,
            SUM(RackRate) AS Spend,
            SUM(Impressions) AS Impressions,
            1 + DATEDIFF(Now(), MIN(StartDate)) AS Days,
            DATE_SUB(MAX(EndDate), INTERVAL 11 Day) AS RenewalDate,
            MAX(StartDate) AS CurrentOrNextStartDate
        FROM
            Contract
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Creative On Creative.ContractId = Contract.Id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN CreativeLog On Creative.Id = CreativeLog.CreativeId            
        GROUP BY
            CampaignId
    ) AS Contracts ON Campaign.Id = Contracts.CampaignId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            CampaignId,
            Id,
            Optin,
            StartDate
        FROM
            Contract
    ) AS LastContract ON Campaign.Id = LastContract.CampaignId AND Contracts.CurrentOrNextStartDate = LastContract.StartDate
WHERE
    Campaign.AgencyId = '04ba6b28-a7a0-4448-b21f-9f2b00a4621b'
ORDER BY
    RenewalDate,
    Location.Name,
    Inventory.Section
```

I haven't made it past here:

```
_session.QueryOver<Contract>()
    .Left.JoinQueryOver<Contract>(campaign => campaign.Contracts).List()
```

Namely because nhibernate is generating an on clause between there two table alias Id == Id when it should be CampaignId == Id.

```
FROM Contract this_ left outer join Contract contract1_ on this_.Id=contract1_.Id
```

Contract's "Contracts" property is a self referencing relationship. It is not 1:1 tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've pretty much concluded this can't be done in queryover. At least not in an optimal way. The inability to join a projection and then select from it is pretty much a show stopper.

Answer (score 0):

you need to show or explain how your mappings are done. If you are going to be joining `Contract` to itself, then you need to tell it what to join on, otherwise it does it on the primary key. If you are on the latest nhibernate I believe you can do a a `.With` and tell it to join to the different column. If its no there yet you can do it with the `.UnderlyingCriteria`